# Isn't a perfect economic system always in debt?

Tags: quantitative

Let's say in a simple world, we have 3 persons, a banker, a businessman and a worker. Then we apply the current monetary system in this economy. So for the system to get started, we need a banker to create money for this economy. The banker lends the businessman USD120 (money created out of thin air) for 1 day with 10% interest to start a business to make food for everyone. (As you can see the total population is only 3). The businessman hires the worker to make food from whatever source for USD40 wages. (Let’s assumed the production can supply more then 3 persons) Then the businessman sells the food in the market for USD40 per meal. Obviously everyone needs to eat so the banker and worker will buy 1 meal each. The businessman himself gets the meal for free of course. In the end of the day, here is the accounting for this economy:

- The businessman started off with USD120, he paid USD40 wages and made USD80
  from selling the food. Therefore his net worth was USD160.
- The worker earns USD40 and spends USD40 for food. (Balance zero).
- The banker didn't have money to buy food, so he "created" the money
  to buy food for himself. Therefore in total he had created USD160 for
  the economy.
- The businessman has to pay the banker back the principal USD120 +
  interest USD12. So his net worth now is USD160 - USD132 = USD28.
- The banker made USD12 after cancelling out the debt USD120. So he took
  USD12 to offset USD40 he spent earlier. However he left with USD28 in
  debt which is exactly the balance of the economy.

Questions:

1. With this simplest model of economy, can I say that money creation (or quantitative easing) is nothing wrong at all?
2. Let's assume that the banker is also a government, if the economy is well managed, isn't the government always be in debt for the sake of public interest?
3. If the above is true, can we say that a government with surplus in accounting would mean poverty in public? (For example, if the banker would have collected income tax say 20% from the worker, he would not have enough to buy food. Of cause instead of becoming poor the worker could also ask for a pay rise in order to make a living. But that would affect businessman's income too.)
4. A super well managed economy will leave no one in excess/lack of money but fulfill the need of living which is goods and services that everyone gets to enjoy. (For instance if the food price was USD12/meal and wages was USD12, then everyone including banker will have zero balance. Isn't this a perfect economic system?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about economics, and is too broad.

Comment: Hi user9486, welcome to quant.SE. You're question is certainly of interest but Joshua Ulrich is right that it's too broad and not on-topic.

Comment: Hi Joshua, Bob, should I post this in "Personal Finance & Money" instead?

Comment: No, I don't believe it fits there. It would have been a good fit on the now defunct economics.SE. I'm afraid you  have to look outside the StackExchange Network for this one.